# How to list filenames from a folder using Jquery and AJAX

Tags: ajax

I had googled a lot about this topic and finally I got a code for my solution. When I'm running this code in my browser error part is running and an alert is being generated. Success part never runs.

I'm running code on my browser with no servers or localhost installed on my system.

I also had all required folders used in code and file.

code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>load demo</title>
        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>  
        <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var fileextension=".jpg";
                var dir="Images/";
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: dir,
                    async:false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#fileNames").html('<ul>');
                        $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                            var filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///",""); 
                            $("#fileNames").append( '<li>'+ filename +'</li>');

                        });
                        $("#fileNames").append('</ul>');
                    },

                    error: function(){
                        alert('error loading images');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='fileNames'> 
            <h3>Showing List of Files</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use this method as the HTML layout cannot be shown when index.html exists. Use PHP to achieve so instead.

Comment: I have to use only jquery, ajax and html. No server side scripting is being used like php. also their is no server acting on my system.